# strword can be how can split used vbcrlf

Tags: vb.net

How can split that items? I don't have anything else to do, which is what the textbox results look like and I don't know how to extract the values correctly from it.

```
Dim lines() As String = TxtResultToString1.Lines
For i As Integer = 1 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim strWords = lines(i).Split(vbCrLf)
    MsgBox(strWords(0))
Next
```

Items: this looks like it in the textbox

```
{ item = , Count = 1 }
{ item = 13, Count = 1 }
{ item = 17, Count = 1 }
{ item = 31, Count = 1 }
{ item = 5, Count = 1 }
{ item = 8, Count = 1 }
{ item = 77, Count = 2 }
{ item = 68, Count = 1 }
{ item = 21, Count = 1 }
{ item = 71, Count = 1 }
{ item = 40, Count = 1 }
{ item = 14, Count = 1 }
{ item = 49, Count = 1 }
{ item = 45, Count = 1 }
{ item = 29, Count = 1 }
{ item = 36, Count = 1 }
{ item = 44, Count = 1 }
```

In another textbox I want to do the following:
Textbox2.Lines=

```
    13 17 31
    17 31 5
    31 5 8
    8 77 68
    68 21 71
    21 71 40
    71 40 14
    40 14 49
    14 49 45
    49 45 29
    45 29 36
    29 36 44
```

Comment: How does it make sense to split a line on line breaks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to substring a string fixed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199113/how-to-substring-a-string-fixed-value)

Answer (score 0):

First I parsed the lines in the text box to extract the item value. I split the line by the comma and then element (0) is split by the equals sign and trimmed. The result is add to the list. Then looping through the list I use a string builder to build the new lines. The minus 3 avoides an index out of range.

```
Private Sub ItemArrangement()
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines
    For i = 1 To TextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
        Dim num = lines(i).Split(","c)(0).Split("="c)(1).Trim
        lst.Add(num)
    Next
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To lst.Count - 3
        sb.AppendLine($"{lst(i)} {lst(i + 1)} {lst(i + 2)}")
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

What you showed as output missed the line starting with 5. If this was intentional you will have to adjust the code.

My output in TextBox2 looked like this.

```
13 17 31
17 31 5
31 5 8
5 8 77
8 77 68
77 68 21
68 21 71
21 71 40
71 40 14
40 14 49
14 49 45
49 45 29
45 29 36
29 36 44
```